# Proof of Arnold Conjecture for monotone symplectic manifolds

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry

I have a question about the proof of the Arnold conjecture for monotone symplectic manifolds as it is explained in http://www.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/floer.pdf: Namely the author on page 32 says that the Arnold conjecture would immediately follow from a theorem 3.7 on the same page. But as far as I see, the theorem requires a further assumption on the Hamiltonian, namely that it has to be contained in some dense set $H_{\mbox{reg}}$ introduced on page 13. My question therefore is: How can we deduce the Arnold conjecture for a general Hamiltonian and not just for a generic one from this construction of Floer homology? Or is the intention of the above paper to just prove the Arnold Conjecture for such a set of Hamiltonians and not necessarily for every Hamiltonian?
Also I have found another point in the proof, which I am not sure about: Namely the author on page 23 has to introduce the Conley-Zehnder index and thus to assume that the $1$-periodic orbit is contractible to assign an index to him. I would then like to know: Does this really mean, we have to make a further restriction on the Hamiltonian and have to assume that every $1$-periodic orbit is contractible?
Every help with one of these questions will be appreciated. It somehow looks to me as if ther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for the Floer boundary map to be well-defined, we require a Floer regular *pair* $(H_t, J_t)$ (we want a family of $\omega$-compatible $J_t$ so we have a nice metric with which to take gradients for Floer's equation). So if we're given an $H_t$ to define the Floer homology groups with, we can hope that maybe there is a family $J_t$ of almost complex structures such that $(H_t, J_t)$ is Floer regular. This turns out to be possible -- see for example Exercise 19.22 in [Oh's notes](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~oh/all.pdf) (these notes focus on the semipositive case, but monotone symplectic manifolds are semipositive).

Answer (score 4):

To prove the Arnold conjecture for monotone symplectic manifolds, it is enough to assume that the Hamiltonian satisfies the genericity condition that all (contractible) 1-periodic solutions are regular. You can then define Floer homology for a generic J. The periodic orbits produced by the proof are all contractible.